# Brew install not working on watchman

Tags: installation, homebrew

I am on a mac os high sierra, and typing to install watchman

```
Kishores-MacBook-Pro:~ kishore$ brew install watchman
Error: Could not create /usr/local/Cellar
Check you have permission to write to /usr/local
Kishores-MacBook-Pro:~ kishore$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
Kishores-MacBook-Pro:~ kishore$
```

Comment: try `brew prune`, `brew doctor`, and `brew update`  Does any of these commands give you an error message?

Comment: no they dont @JosephK.